# C# add new text to string WITHOUT copy it previous value

Tags: c#, string

I have string that i need to combine with another string , for example

```
string string1 = "cars"; // the text is just for example 
string string2 = "white";
// then
string string1 = string1 + string2;
// or
string string1 += string2;
```

Alright , at first glance it doesn't have any problem right ? 
NOPE , it does have problem

when the `string.length` / the string contain A LOT OF CHARACTER , for example when it contain 100.000 word , it start to get laggy or freeze when i put it inside loop, because it need to copy 100.000 word plus word from the other string everytime it combines string1 with string2 .

Is the any alternative way to add new text to string that contain massive amount of word ?

Comment: take a look at [StringBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/stringbuilder)

Comment: Yeah, concatination isn't the best option, StringBuilder would do well for you :)

Comment: Where do you get this string from? Could it be read into a stream?

Comment: I have take a look at it and it's exactly what i wanted ! thanks everyone :) !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The correct way to accumulate strings in c# is using `StringBuilder`.
Example:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
sb.Append("...");
sb.Append("...");
....
var result = sb.ToString()
```

Your solution appear to lag, since every time you "modify" a string a brand new one is created instead, so the garbage collector get a little crazy...